# Python Pipeline shows only one step

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, pipeline, tf-idf

I try to create SVM classifier for short texts with TfIdf as first step. When I create Pipeline, fir it and get accuracy scores - everything looks right.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,4), max_features=50000, max_df=0.5, use_idf=True, norm='l2') 
classifier = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', max_iter=50, alpha=1e-05, penalty='l2')
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('tfidf', vectorizer), ('clf', classifier)])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But when I load created model and print it I get only one step - TfIdf instead of two - TfIdf and SVM.

```
print(pipe)
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=0.5, max_features=50000, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 4), norm='l2', preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True...m_state=None, shuffle=True, tol=None,
       validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=0, warm_start=False))])
```

I assume that I don't understand how the Pipeline works exactly but in every example that I saw there were as much steps as it was loaded in the Pipeline at first.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It is because the output is truncated. The arguments shuffle, tol, validation_fraction, verbose, and warm_start belongs to the SGDClassifier.

Comment: @justhalf thank you very much! How can I see whole output?

Comment: @justhalf Upd: pipeline.steps =) How can I upvote your answer? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It was a comment. Let me change that to an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the output by printing the pipeline directly is truncated, and doesn't show the whole output.
For example, the arguments shuffle, tol, validation_fraction, verbose, and warm_start belongs to the [`SGDClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html).

As you have found yourself in the comments, to avoid truncation, you can print the steps directly using `pipeline.steps`.